# get old row value in appscript and update

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

***I was working to synchronize sheets with each other in appscript.The code basically synchronizes google sheets with a main database sheet. In case of change in any sheet the sheets are synced based on  a trigger onEdit***
The code below works fine when there is any change in any cell but when  I delete a complete row at once .It does not work. Can anyone please help

```
function onEdit(e) {
   
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  Logger.log(column)
  if (sheet.getName() == "Database") {
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
   
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
     Logger.log(e.changeType)
    var identifier = data[row-1][0];
    var sheetName = data[row-1][2];
    if(identifier && sheetName){
   

    var otherSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
   
    if (otherSheet) {
      var rowIndex = findRowIndexByIdentifier(otherSheet, identifier);
      var checkname=otherSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 2).getValues()[0]
      var checksite=otherSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 3).getValues()[0]
      var checkident=otherSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1).getValues()[0]
      var stat=otherSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 12).getValues()[0]
      var  numsite=returnsite(checksite[0])
      var numname=returnnameindex(numsite)
     
      if (rowIndex > 0) {
        otherSheet.getRange(rowIndex, column).setValue(e.value);
        if(column==2){
         
          toemail=redacteur_emails[numname]
          sendemail("timar72243@asoflex.com"," UPDATE ON SITE "+checksite+" Article No: "+checkident,"The status is" +stat)
        }
        if(column==12 && stat=="A réviser"){
         
        
          toemail=redacteur_emails[numname]
          sendemail("timar72243@asoflex.com"," UPDATE ON SITE "+checksite+" Article No:"+checkident,"The status is"+stat)

        }
        if(column==12 && (stat=="A réviser" ||  stat=="En cours de révision par CM")){
         
          for(var i=0;i<content_managers_emails.length;i++){
            toemail=content_managers_emails[i]
            sendemail("zukkoyilte@gufum.com"," UPDATE ON SITE "+checksite+" Article No: "+checkident," The status is "+stat)
          }

        }
        else if(column==12 && (stat=="A publier sous WP" ||  stat=="A reviser par integrateur")){
          for(var i=0;i<integrateurs_emails.length;i++){
            toemail=integrateurs_emails[i]
            sendemail("zukkoyilte@gufum.com"," UPDATE ON SITE "+checksite+" Article No: "+checkident," The status is "+stat)
         
          }
        }
        else if(column==12 && (stat=="Livré" ||  stat=="Publié")){
          for(var i=0;i<admins_emails.length;i++){
            toemail=admins_emails[i]
            Logger.log("arrived12")
            sendemail("zukkoyilte@gufum.com"," UPDATE ON SITE "+checksite+" Article No: "+checkident," The status is "+stat)
          }
        }

      }
      else{
       var rowToAppend = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       
        otherSheet.appendRow(rowToAppend[0])

      }
    }
    }
  }
  else {
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    var databaseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
    var identifier = "";
    var rowIndex = e.range.getRow();
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      identifier = data[i][0];
      var databaseRowIndex = findRowIndexByIdentifier(databaseSheet, identifier);
      if (databaseRowIndex > 0 && sheetName == databaseSheet.getRange(databaseRowIndex, 3).getValue()) {
        databaseSheet.getRange(databaseRowIndex, column).setValue(data[i][column-1]);
      }
    }
  }

  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are deleting a row by hand, this will require an `onChange` function, rather than an `onEdit`.

**Unfortunately**, there is no way to get the old values as you are able to do with `onEdit` at this time.

If this isn't necessarily a problem, the main event property you will be looking for is `if (e.changeType === 'REMOVE_ROW') { ... }`.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change

Comment: But my actual problem is that i want to remove the same row from the other sheet.even if i use onchange. I can't do that.. is there any way to do the functionality i want

Comment: And I'm actually syncing two sheets for any change. Everything works fine when only single cell is modified.. but when i delete complete Row at a time. The syncing does not work

Comment: As i have to match row in the other sheet to delete it from other sheet as well.so on change won't actually work for me

Comment: Are they identical sheets? Are other users accessing your sheet, and if so, frequently? Regarding onChange, this is the only way to trigger when a row is removed, so you will have to work within that framework.

Comment: I have a main sheet, that is database.the database sheet contains records that are divided into other sheets. Whenever there is any edit in database tab i update it in the corresponding sheet with the help of column that contains value of sheet name in database tab in the row being edited

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that when a row is completely deleted i have no clue or trail to backtrack or track to update it in the corresponding sheet. And the database sheet is only being accessed by me

Comment: @ShaheerIlyas I understand your issue of figuring out which row has been removed; but again, you have to work within the parameters of onChange if you want anything to trigger with row removal. Your best, and maybe only course of action, will be to pull all data from the database sheet and compare it to your other sheets for the inequality. (on row removal)

Comment: Yeah .  After hunting alot.. the thing i came up with is to compare all files with database after every edit. But what i think is that it will have a very high complexity